# angular 7 build app - replace assets url with real url

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli, angular7, angular-builder

In an Angular 7 app i have different assets, images, fonts etc. All are located in src/assets/images or src/assets/fonts, etc

I my files i use them like this: `<img src="/assets/images/img.png">`

angular.json look like this:

```
 .....
 "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ]
 .....
```

When building I use:

`ng build --prod --build-optimizer --deploy-url=https://cdn.domain.com`

This will replace all the reference to assets resource from this:

`<img src="/assets/images/img.png">`

to this:

`<img src="https://cdn.domain.com/assets/images/img.png">`

My question how I can remove the `assets/images` path when building so that after building the output will be:

`<img src="https://cdn.domain.com/img.png">`

Comment: Is this <img src="/assets/images/img.png"> tag is in your index.html file?

Comment: No it is in the templates but basically all urls to local assets/images, assets/fonts get replaced including the url to the files in index.html. It is what I want but I want the assets/path to be removed ... the thinng is that I will publish all files to cdn in a flat folder so I won't be able to have the folder path structure from my assets folder

Comment: I just generated a new App with Angular CLI: 7.1.4. Executed your build command: ng build --prod etc. and links does not get replaced with the full url. All assets are copied into a dist folder under 'assets'. Can you try again on a brand new project?

Comment: Updated link for asset configuration: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#asset-config

Answer (score 2):

You could replace

```
 "assets": [
    ...
    "src/assets",
    ...
  ]
```

by

```
"assets": [
  ...
  { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets", "output": "/" },
  ...
]
```

All the files will be in "/dist/environment/" and not in "/dist/environment/..."

Then in your html files, use directly :

```
<img src="/img.png">
```

Have a look here : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md

:-)