# Build Angular app with absolute urls for images

Tags: javascript, angular

Is it possible to build an Angular 10 app to have absolute urls instead of relative ones for the images?

Our app is deployed to and hosted on a production server `https://hostingserver/hostedApps/myApp/` but is rendered on a different server which is the actual main user-focused server `https://productionserver/apps/myApp` which has the main page containing content other than the Angular app. The Angular app is just embedded into this page.
The `angular.json` file has:

```
"baseHref": "",
"deployUrl": "https://hostingserver/hostedApps/myApp/"
```

and everything builds fine. The output `index.html` file has absolute links to the js files, such as `<script src="https://hostingserver/hostedApps/myApp/main.js" defer></script>` which is perfect but the images are all still rendered like

```
<img src="./assets/images/myImage.svg">
```

which when viewed in the browser console is a 404 as it's looking for:

```
https://productionserver/apps/myApp/assets/images/myImage.svg
```

instead of

```
https://hostingserver/hostedApps/myApp/assets/images/myImage.svg
```

The index.html base href is `<base href="">` because anything else would interfere with other elements on the hosted page.

Comment: I am not that familiar with it but maybe you can use image hosting sites for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular 7 build app - replace assets url with real url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962936/angular-7-build-app-replace-assets-url-with-real-url)

Comment: @MarioPetrovic I'm afraid that doesn't do what I want. The images are all still relative urls

Comment: Ok, hope you find a solution.